# Condense string to N characters

Tags: javascript

I would like a non library solution (i.e. something I can implement in my own code) for the following problem:

Given a string S and a limit number N, show S in a condensed form containing N characters including a "summary character" like `.` e.g.:

```
let S = "some description goes here";
let N = 10;
console.log(condense(S, N));
```

Expected output:

```
som...here
```

this should be trivial to implement with something like this:

```js
function condense(s, n) {
  if (s.length > n) {
    const pre = s.slice(0, n/2);
    const post = s.slice(s.length - n/2);
    return pre + '...' + post;
  }
  return s;
}
```

but would like to check if there's a more efficient or idiomatic way to implement it; looks like the code above would get too ugly in order to check all special cases.

Comment: What special cases?

Comment: Are you expected to handle all writing systems sets or just western style ones? I'm asking because for some languages if you try to remove a character you actually end up with a longer string rather than a shorter one (due to some characters being compounds of others).

Comment: Is the number of dots in the output to be dynamic? Always 3? Does that leave N - 3 characters to be placed around it? What if N=2 how would you condense "abc"?

Comment: Do you have to handle emojis and such?

Comment: @robertklep Input string being empty, null or undefined, length being equal to the limit but condensing to display just the extra `...`, non ASCII characters being present hence the length not being representative of the resulting string width - I do have unicode characters and parsing them as `\uXXX` where they appear makes my code really clunky - I know there's libraries that can help but I'd prefer a non library solution,

Comment: @apokryfos Correct there can be unicode characters

Comment: @InSync I don't have any requirement on emojis, but Chinese yes or a description where there's Chinese mixed with English (I guess it doesn't change much, emojis would just be another unicode character)

Comment: not being 100% sure about this but if you start reading one character at a time from both start and end you can either end when you've read n-3 characters (with 3 characters needed for ...) or less than n characters. Suggesting this because .slice might split a unicode character in two breaking the text

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) may be useful. Also keep in mind Chinese characters may not fit in 16 bits so may span 2 string indices, which is something you need to account for somehow

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

1. With Array splicing
2. With RegExp

#### Array splicing:

```js
function condense(s, n, filler="...") {
    s = [...String(s)];
    if (s.length > n) {
        n -= filler.length;
        if (n < 0) return null; // Not possible 
        s.splice(n >> 1, s.length - n, filler);
    }
    return s.join("");
}

const tests = [
    '',
    'abcdef',
    'abcdefg',
    'something',
    null,
    undefined,
    '@',
    '99'
];

for (const s of tests) {
    console.log(s, '->', condense(s, 6));
}
console.log('test', '->', condense('test', 2)); // Not possible (null output)
```

#### RegExp

```js
function condense(s, n, filler="...") {
    n -= filler.length;
    if (n < 0) return null; // Not possible
    const regex = RegExp(`(.{${n>>1}}).{${filler.length+1},}(.{${(n+1)>>1}})`, "gsu");
    return String(s).replace(regex, `$1${filler}$2`);
}

const tests = [
    '',
    'abcdef',
    'abcdefg',
    'something',
    null,
    undefined,
    '@',
    '99'
];

for (const s of tests) {
    console.log(s, '->', condense(s, 6));
}
console.log('test', '->', condense('test', 2)); // Not possible (null output)
```

The above solutions do not work well with graphemes that combine emoji characters, like '‍‍‍'. If you need support for those too, then use [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) in the Array variant:

```
s = Array.from(new Intl.Segmenter().segment(String(s)), x => x.segment)
```

```js
function condense(s, n, filler="...") {
    s = Array.from(new Intl.Segmenter().segment(String(s)), x => x.segment)

    if (s.length > n) {
        n -= filler.length;
        if (n < 0) return null; // Not possible 
        s.splice(n >> 1, s.length - n, filler);
    }
    return s.join("");
}

const tests = [
    '',
    'abcdef',
    'abcdefg',
    'something',
    null,
    undefined,
    '‍‍‍@', // Starts with a combined emoji
    '99'
];

for (const s of tests) {
    console.log(s, '->', condense(s, 6));
}
```